# ST_Intersects() query took too long

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgis, spatial-index

I'm working on a query using the PostGIS extension that implements a 'spatial join' work. Running the query took an incredibly long time and failed in the end. The query is as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX buffer_table_geom_idx ON buffer_table USING GIST (geom);
CREATE INDEX point_table_geom_idx ON point_table USING GIST (geom);

SELECT
    point_table.*,
    buffer_table.something
FROM
    point_table
    LEFT JOIN buffer_table ON ST_Intersects (buffer_table.geom, point_table.geom);
```

where the point_table stands for a table that contains over 10 million rows of point records; the buffer_table stands for a table that contains only one multi-polygon geometry.

I would want to know if there is anything wrong with my code and ways to adjust. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the query plan? -> `explain analyse` 
Also, could you add some sample data?

Comment: @JimJones Hi, Jim. I run the 'EXPLAIN ANALYSE' query in PgAdmin4. However, the query is unable to be run. The interface keeps showing 'Waiting for the query to complete'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `LEFT JOIN` you're going through every single record of `point_table` and therefore ignoring the index. Try this and see the difference:

```
SELECT point_table.*
FROM point_table
JOIN buffer_table ON ST_Contains(buffer_table.geom, point_table.geom);
```

##### Divide and conquer with [`ST_SubDivide`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html)

Considering the size of your multipolygon (see comments), it might be interesting to divide it into smaller pieces, so that the number of vertices for each containment/intersection calculation also gets reduced, consequently making the query less expensive.

First divide the large geometry into smaller pieces and store in another table (you can also use a CTE/Subquery)

```
CREATE TABLE buffer_table_divided AS
SELECT ST_SubDivide(geom) AS geom FROM buffer_table

CREATE INDEX buffer_table_geom_divided_idx ON buffer_table_divided USING GIST (geom);
```

.. and perform your query once again against this new table:

```
SELECT point_table.*
FROM point_table
JOIN buffer_table_divided d ON ST_Contains (d.geom, point_table.geom);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=abe005073d3006a7f616d0bc8ae28026)

Comment: Hi, Jim. Thanks for your fast response. I feel like escaping 'left' is not the fundamental solution to my problem for a 10 million-row table. 

Changing from 'left join' to 'join' does trigger the index scanning process. I tried the method you proposed to a 1000-row table.

However, I can still not run the query once I escape the 'left' for my full-size table.

Could it be possible that there is something wrong with the spatial indexing process?

Comment: @user12949097 could it be that your query is simply returning more data than you can handle in your client? even 1% of 10m points is a lot to render ;) can you add the query plan from `explain` (without `analyse`)?

Comment: @user12949097 also, how big is your `multipolygon`?

Comment: Jim, the EXPLAIN ... query result is listed below. My multipolygon has 20k small buffers.
`Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..35355.90 rows=12169 width=143)
  ->  Seq Scan on metrostationsunion_gcj02 buffer_table  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=36)
  ->  Index Scan using temporary2_geomo_idx on temporary2 point_table  (cost=0.42..35342.72 rows=1217 width=139)
        Index Cond: (geomo && buffer_table.geom)
        Filter: st_intersects(buffer_table.geom, geomo)
`

Comment: @user12949097 without proper indentation it is very hard to read a query plan. Add it your question and format it :) I added another strategy that might speed up your spatial queries.. 20k polygons in a single multipolygon can get really expensive to perform containment operations over

Comment: Jim, I appreciate your informative guides, and which are really helpful. I finally figured out the problem. Before implementing ST_Intersects(), I did ST_Union() to make 20k buffers into one. It turns out that combining 20k buffers into one kills the ST_Intersects() process.

Comment: @user12949097 that's also a pretty good idea +1. happy coding :)