# Is it possible to accelerate this postgress / postgis statement?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap

I have a Postgres database with a postgis extention installed and filles with open street map data.

With the following SQL statement :

```
SELECT                                                                
    l.osm_id,
    sum(
        st_area(st_intersection(ST_Buffer(l.way, 30), p.way))
        /
        st_area(ST_Buffer(l.way, 30))
    ) as green_fraction
FROM planet_osm_line AS l
INNER JOIN planet_osm_polygon AS p ON ST_Intersects(l.way, ST_Buffer(p.way,30))
WHERE p.natural in ('water') or p.landuse in ('forest') GROUP BY l.osm_id;
```

I calculate a "green" score.

My goal is to create a "green" score for each osm_id.

Which means; how much of a road is near a water, forrest or something similar.

To do so:

I Create a 30 meter buffer around each way, and calculate the intersection between that buffered way and any green features nearby.

I am using 'green features' to refer to polygons in OpenStreetMap's database, such as a park.

Is it possbile to accelerate this calculation?

One thing I id is to create 2 indices in a hope to accelerate the calculation:

```
CREATE INDEX way_index_2 on planet_osm_polygon USING gist(way) WHERE "natural" IN ('water','wood','forest','hill','valley');
CREATE INDEX way_index_3 on planet_osm_polygon USING gist(way) WHERE "landuse" IN ('forest');
```

Here is an "explain" to this statement:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT                                                                
    l.osm_id,
    sum(
        st_area(st_intersection(ST_Buffer(l.way, 30), p.way))
        /
        st_area(ST_Buffer(l.way, 30))
    ) as green_fraction
FROM planet_osm_line AS l
INNER JOIN planet_osm_polygon AS p ON ST_Intersects(l.way, ST_Buffer(p.way,30))
WHERE p.natural in ('water') or p.landuse in ('forest') GROUP BY l.osm_id limit 1;
                                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=17816.83..133789235.22 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=1575643.737..1575651.862 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=816315 read=221878, temp read=313661 written=73938
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=17816.83..1435958589062981.00 rows=10734420 width=16) (actual time=1575643.723..1575651.847 rows=1 loops=1)
         Group Key: l.osm_id
         Buffers: shared hit=816315 read=221878, temp read=313661 written=73938
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=17816.83..1433802261939271.50 rows=28652652777 width=448) (actual time=978502.788..1575648.857 rows=8 loops=1)
               Join Filter: st_intersects(l.way, st_buffer(p.way, '30'::double precision, ''::text))
               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 6528525
               Buffers: shared hit=816315 read=221878, temp read=313661 written=73938
               ->  Index Scan using osm_id_idx on planet_osm_line l  (cost=0.44..1242021.57 rows=22671610 width=247) (actual time=5.963..6.181 rows=6 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=5 read=3
               ->  Materialize  (cost=17816.39..1445364.98 rows=1263812 width=201) (actual time=85.181..4605.942 rows=1088089 loops=6)
                     Buffers: shared hit=380236 read=220348, temp read=313661 written=73938
                     ->  Gather  (cost=17816.39..1403253.92 rows=1263812 width=201) (actual time=510.609..1066.182 rows=1250378 loops=1)
                           Workers Planned: 4
                           Workers Launched: 4
                           Buffers: shared hit=380236 read=220348
                           ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on planet_osm_polygon p  (cost=16816.39..1275872.72 rows=315953 width=201) (actual time=447.168..9410.838 rows=250076 loops=5)
                                 Recheck Cond: (("natural" = ANY ('{water,wood,forest,hill,valley}'::text[])) OR (landuse = 'forest'::text))
                                 Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2554266
                                 Filter: (("natural" = 'water'::text) OR (landuse = 'forest'::text))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 53217
                                 Heap Blocks: lossy=1
                                 Buffers: shared hit=380236 read=220348
                                 ->  BitmapOr  (cost=16816.39..16816.39 rows=1554297 width=0) (actual time=491.891..491.893 rows=0 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=7797
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on way_index_2  (cost=0.00..7822.79 rows=750359 width=0) (actual time=413.690..413.690 rows=737741 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=3758
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on way_index_3  (cost=0.00..8361.69 rows=803938 width=0) (actual time=78.198..78.198 rows=783702 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=4039
 Planning Time: 0.315 ms
 Execution Time: 1575673.609 ms
(32 rows)
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a short schema of the both tables;

```
                                                Table 

"public.planet_osm_line"
       Column       |           Type            | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
--------------------+---------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 osm_id             | bigint                    |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 access             | text                      |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 addr:housename     | text                      |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 addr:housenumber   | text                      |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 addr:interpolation | text                      |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 admin_level        | text                      |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
....
natural            | text                      |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 



Indexes:
    "highway_idx" btree (highway)
    "motorway_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = 'motorway'::text
    "motorway_trunk_primary_secondary_tertiary_unclassified_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = ANY (ARRAY['motorway'::text, 'trunk'::text, 'primary'::text, 'secondary'::text, 'tertiary'::text, 'unclassified'::text])
    "name_idx" btree (name)
    "osm_id_idx" btree (osm_id)
    "planet_osm_line_osm_id_idx" btree (osm_id)
    "planet_osm_line_way_idx" gist (way)
    "primary_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = 'primary'::text
    "primary_secondary_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = ANY (ARRAY['primary'::text, 'secondary'::text])
    "primary_secondary_tertiary_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = ANY (ARRAY['primary'::text, 'secondary'::text, 'tertiary'::text])
    "primary_secondary_tertiary_unclassified_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = ANY (ARRAY['primary'::text, 'secondary'::text, 'tertiary'::text, 'unclassified'::text])
    "secondary_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = 'secondary'::text
    "secondary_tertiary_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = ANY (ARRAY['secondary'::text, 'tertiary'::text])
    "tertiary_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = 'tertiary'::text
    "tertiary_secondary_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = ANY (ARRAY['tertiary'::text, 'unclassified'::text])
    "trunk_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = 'trunk'::text
    "trunk_primary_secondary_tertiary_unclassified_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = ANY (ARRAY['trunk'::text, 'primary'::text, 'secondary'::text, 'tertiary'::text, 'unclassified'::text])
    "unclassified_idx" gist (way) WHERE highway = 'unclassified'::text
    "way_idx" gist (way)
    "way_index_1" gist (way)
    "way_index_4" gist (way) WHERE "natural" = ANY (ARRAY['water'::text, 'wood'::text, 'forest'::text, 'hill'::text, 'valley'::text])
    "way_index_5" gist (way) WHERE landuse = 'forest'::text
Triggers:
    planet_osm_line_osm2pgsql_valid BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON planet_osm_line FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION planet_osm_line_osm2pgsql_valid()
Access method: heap
```

And:

```
                                                 Table "public.planet_osm_polygon"
       Column       |          Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
--------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 osm_id             | bigint                  |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 access             | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 addr:housename     | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 addr:housenumber   | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 addr:interpolation | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 admin_level        | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 aerialway          | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 aeroway            | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 amenity            | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 area               | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 barrier            | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
landuse            | text                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 


Indexes:
    "fuel_toilet_parking_restaurant_idex" gist (way) WHERE amenity = ANY (ARRAY['fuel'::text, 'toilets'::text, 'parking'::text, 'restaurant'::text, 'cafe'::text, 'pub'::text, 'ice_cream'::text, 'biergarten'::text])
    "planet_osm_polygon_osm_id_idx" btree (osm_id)
    "planet_osm_polygon_way_idx" gist (way)
    "viewpoint_attraction_guest_house_idex" gist (way) WHERE tourism = ANY (ARRAY['viewpoint '::text, 'attraction'::text, 'guest_house'::text])
    "way_index_2" gist (way) WHERE "natural" = ANY (ARRAY['water'::text, 'wood'::text, 'forest'::text, 'hill'::text, 'valley'::text])
    "way_index_3" gist (way) WHERE landuse = 'forest'::text
Triggers:
    planet_osm_polygon_osm2pgsql_valid BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON planet_osm_polygon FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION planet_osm_polygon_osm2pgsql_valid()
Access method: heap
```

**UPDATE**:

**planet_osm_polygon**

```
wood               | text                    |           |          |                                                     | extended |             |              | 
 z_order            | integer                 |           |          |                                                     | plain    |             |              | 
 way_area           | real                    |           |          |                                                     | plain    |             |              | 
 way                | geometry(Geometry,3857) |           |          |                                                     | main     |             |              | 
 way_buffer_30      | geometry(Polygon)       |           |          |                                                     | external |             |              | 
 way_buffer_30_area | numeric                 |           |          | generated always as (st_area(way_buffer_30)) stored | main     |             |              |
```

AND

**planet_osm_line**

```
way_area           | real                      |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 way                | geometry(LineString,3857) |           |          |         | main     |             |              |
```

Comment: You should run  `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...` and add that output to your question.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I updated the question with EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output

Comment: Try a normal btree index on `planet_osm_polygon(natural, landuse)` for the `where` clause, and a [spatial index](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html) on `planet_osm_line using gist(way)` for the join. An index on `planet_osm_line(osm_id)` might help the group by. You also might want to try [dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) and [gis.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The  spatial index on planet_osm_line is already in place. CREATE INDEX way_idx ON planet_osm_line USING gist(way);
Also  An index on planet_osm_line(osm_id). From what I understand these are not being used or ignored.

Comment: Have you run [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) on the tables?

Comment: Yep. I was wondering if I could limit the area by a bbox something with  planet_osm_line.way && ST_Transform(
      ST_MakeEnvelope( 9.07805053255787 , 47.4781579714091 , 12.0860304569466 , 49.478071667293 ,4326),3857
       );" ?

Comment: @Andreas Can you show the full schema of each table? That will tell us what the indexes and types are.

Comment: @Schwern Sure: I updated the question to include the most of the tables schema.

Comment: @Andreas Would you mind editing the DDLs to show the `planet_osm_polygon.way` and  `planet_osm_line.way` column definitions? Also, it looks like you're building quite a lot of indices - you might want drop the ones that aren't helping any queries that run often. If you often run complex queries that you don't ever repeat, you can build custom clones of these tables, with custom indexes. It's not uncommon that when you work with huge sets of geometries it's faster to build and customise a clone than to re-use the original table.

Comment: Ups sorry left out the important bit :) I updated the question to include planet_osm_polygon.way and planet_osm_line.way column definitions.

Comment: Maybe it's something about gist indicies I don't understand, but a lot of those indexes seem redundant.

Comment: Always keep ST_Subdivide in mind when dealing with large geometries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68622815/2275388 cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer as much as a bunch of comments too long for a comment format:

```sql
alter system set default_toast_compression=lz4;

alter table planet_osm_polygon 
    add column way_buffer_30 geometry, 
    alter column way_buffer_30 set storage external,
    add column way_buffer_30_area numeric 
        generated always as (st_area(way_buffer_30)) stored;
update planet_osm_polygon 
    set way_buffer_30=st_buffer(way,30,'quad_segs=1');
create index osmp_way_buffer_30_gix on planet_osm_polygon 
    using gist(way_buffer_30) with (fillfactor=100);
cluster verbose planet_osm_polygon using osmp_way_buffer_30_gix;

alter table planet_osm_line
    add column way_buffer_30 geometry, 
    alter column way_buffer_30 set storage external,
    add column way_buffer_30_area numeric 
        generated always as (st_area(way_buffer_30)) stored; 
update planet_osm_line
    set way_buffer_30=st_buffer(way,30,'quad_segs=1');
create index osml_way_buffer_30_gix on planet_osm_line
    using gist(way_buffer_30) with (fillfactor=100);
cluster verbose planet_osm_polygon using osml_way_buffer_30_gix;

SELECT                                                                
    l.osm_id,
    sum(st_area(st_intersection(l.way_buffer_30, p.way))
        / l.way_buffer_30_area
    ) as green_fraction
FROM planet_osm_line AS l
INNER JOIN planet_osm_polygon AS p ON ST_Intersects(l.way, p.way_buffer_30)
WHERE p.natural in ('water') or p.landuse in ('forest') GROUP BY l.osm_id;
```

1. `default_toast_compression=lz4` You're working with polygons, which are likely to be compressed and TOASTed. Default `default_toast_compression=pglz` is typically [slower](https://www.shunlongwei.com/toasts-new-compression-algorithm-lz4-in-postgresql-14-how-fast-can-it-be/) than `lz4`. Note that you need to force a re-write of those tables/columns after altering the setting, otherwise it'll apply as a default only from that point onwards, not affecting anything retroactively.
2. [`storage external`](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2018/09/postgis-external-storage.html) skips one step in retrieving the data if the shapes are big/complex enough. Might be worth it depending on your PostGIS version.
3. [`st_buffer(way,30,'quad_segs=1')`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html#idm15568) you can tweak the third parameter to get a simpler shape, that's easier to compare against. Default `quad_segs=8` can cause your buffer to have 8x more vertices than the input.
4. [`with (fillfactor=100)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) I assume it's a static source table that you replace when a new version is published, rather than maintain the current one yourself. Therefore, indexes can be made static, too (default `fillfactor=90` is meant to account for new rows inserted into the table).
5. [`cluster`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) aligns table pages with the index, making heap fetches faster.
6. An index on the final buffer shape you want to use will be better than an index on a column you plan to use to create it using `ST_Buffer()`. Same goes for `ST_Transform()` - apply it on the column before indexing, not in the query.
7. [*ST_Subdivide all the Things*](https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/11/subdivide.html).
8. You can test if [`ST_DWithin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) speeds up the join compared to your current code and the one suggested above. Be sure to test with a suitable index. Keep in mind the unit of distance depends on the column SRID - if you're using metric you'll get anomalies from systems in imperial/nautical/degrees.

   ```sql
   INNER JOIN planet_osm_polygon AS p ON ST_DWithin(l.way,p.way,30)
   ```
9. You can check if your [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) is at all worth it, and see if it performs better if you narrow it down for the purpose of this query

   ```sql
   create index way_buffer_30_gix on planet_osm_polygon 
   using gist(way_buffer_30) with (fillfactor=100)
   where natural='water' or landuse='forest';
   ```
10. Most of the above only makes sense if that's a one-off operation or if you can clone the target tables so that you don't have to deal with other indexes and settings that are supposed to improve performance of operations that you do on that table more often. You can also filter out whatever you're not interested in at this stage, using that `where` clause.
11. If it's *really* slow, extract a subset of rows from both tables and run your tests on those. To get more reliable results, use [`pgbench`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html) to run your benchmarks.

Comment: Thank you Ill try your suggestions and report. Yes it is a one-off operation. I use SELECT PostGIS_Version();
 3.3 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
(1 row)

Comment: I have an error if I follow the step 3. (ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiPolygon) does not match column type (Polygon))

Comment: You can work around it by removing `(POLYGON)` from the column definiton, making it a generic `geometry`. It's also a good time to re-check if your input should be a MULTILINESTRING to begin with and if you're generally handling it as such.